# Proxy Traffic through HTTP_PROXY API Gateway Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I want to proxy all traffic matching a path to VPC LINK with an Integration type of `HTTP_PROXY`

The setup below works fine

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "rest_api_destination_get_stats_method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_destinationId_stats_resource.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"

  request_parameters = {
    "method.request.path.destinationId" = true
  }

}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "rest_api_get_destinationId_method_integration" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_destinationId_resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.rest_api_destination_get_method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "GET"
  type                    = "HTTP_PROXY"
  uri                     = "http://${module.nlb.lb_dns_name}/destination/{destinationId}"
  connection_type         = "VPC_LINK"
  connection_id           = aws_api_gateway_vpc_link.eb_vpc_link.id

   request_parameters = {
    "integration.request.path.destinationId" = "method.request.path.destinationId"
  }

  //request_tempates is required to explicitly set the statusCode to an integer value of 200
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = jsonencode({
      statusCode = 200
    })
  }

   depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_destinationId_resource,
    aws_api_gateway_resource.rest_api_destination_resource, 
    aws_api_gateway_method.rest_api_destination_get_method,
    aws_api_gateway_vpc_link.eb_vpc_link
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to directly proxy all traffic without having to specify the `request_parameters` ?

Ideally i would like AWS API Gateway to take the `ResourcePath` the cilent has sent and append it to the uri(assume uri is `uri                     = "http://${module.nlb.lb_dns_name}`) and also forward any headers and body that the cilent has sent to API gateway to uri `"http://${module.nlb.lb_dns_name}/{ResourcePath}`

When i change the url to `"http://${module.nlb.lb_dns_name}/{proxy+}"` and remove `request_parameters`, get the following error message while testing the endpoint

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: Illegal character in path at index 85
```

Comment: The "Illegal character" comes from the "{destinationId}" (traditionally '{proxy}') [this comment is to help SEO find this for people following the proxy tradition]
It is appended as plain text to the URI _only if_ you do not specify the request parameters.

This isn't answering your question, I know. But this might help someone fighting the proxy 'request_parameters' aspect missing in their terraform or API Gateway integration setup.